# Removing id from CakePHP form action

Tags: cakephp

```
<form id="RecipeEditForm" method="post" action="/recipes/edit/5">
```

I need to remove /5 from the form action how can i do.
I am using Cakephp 3.

Comment: That will work: `<form id="RecipeEditForm" method="post" action="/recipes/edit">`

Comment: Honestly, can you be more clear what your problem is? For me the sentence "I need to remove /5" goes along with an answer like "Well then go to your source code, go to the line you copy/pasted. Then mark the /5 in your text-editor and press delete". But since you managed to post something to stackoverflow I would assume that you already have the knowledge needed to edit text files ...

Comment: No this will created by default from cake Framework, i am create form like[<?= $this->Form->create($workshopEntity,  ["novalidate" => true,'controller' => 'WorkShop',  'action' => 'edit_form', 'type' => 'POST']);?>]

Comment: Add the actual URL you want in the options array: `'url' => ['controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'edit']`.

Comment: No not set friend...

Comment: I stand with @quant . I can't understand the context, can't give an answer without it.

Comment: I think the requirement is wrong. At least that is 99% probable here.

Answer (score 0):

example, how to enable users to edit only own user account without passing id in url.

```
public function edit()
{
    $user = $this->Users->find()
        ->where(['id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
        ->firstOrFail();

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            /$this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```